# References for properties/examples of breadth in (semi)lattices

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, lattice-theory, posets

This is in some sense following up on my earlier question [Is there existing terminology for this technical condition on semilattices?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/83111/is-there-existing-terminology-for-this-technical-condition-on-semilattices) and the [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/100971) given by NN.

I am currently revising the paper which used the condition mentioned in my question. It was pointed out in NN's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/100971) that the concept is an old and standard one, at least to lattice theorists — namely, it turns out I rediscovered the notion of the "breadth" of a semilattice.

I would like to find **references** that I can cite for the following facts, both of which appear in my paper in order to provide examples:

> 1. The breadth of a semilattice is less than or equal to its height.
> 2. The breadth of a semilattice is less than or equal to its width.

These are easy to prove: but it seems likely that these should be in one of several compendious works on lattice theory or more general partially ordered sets, and I would like to pay my dues to the literature, as it were. Does anyone know of a reference stating these results explicitly?

---

**Definitions of terms.**
Let $(P, \preceq)$ be a partially ordered set. The *height* of $P$ is the sup of the lengths of chains in $P$. The *width* of $P$ is the cardinality of the largest antichain in $P$ (if it is finite, it is also equal, by [Dilworth's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilworth%27s_theorem), to the minimum "number" of chains in $P$ whose union is all of $P$).

Now suppose $P$ is a meet-semilattice, so that each pair $(x,y)$ of elements has a greatest lower bound $x\wedge y$. The breadth of $P$, as far as I can gather from reading fragments of various papers found by searching online, is defined as follows: let $E$ be a finite subset of $P$, let $E^{[n]}$ be the set of all elements of the form $x_1\wedge \dotsb \wedge x_n$, and let
$$ b(E)=\min\{ n\geq 1 \mid E^{[n]}=E^{[n+1]} \} \leq 2^{|E|}. $$
Then the *breadth of $P$* is the supremum of $b(E)$ as we range over all finite subsets $E\subseteq P$.

Comment: Too late, but Gratzer's book (2011 edition) should have useful material.

Comment: @user46855 Thanks - I think I tried quickly checking it before I posted this question, and just found these given as exercises. But perhaps I will check again if I find time.